# Фоновая загрузка страницы и переход на неё

Tags: javascript, html

Есть ли возможность при помощи *JavaScript* в фоновом режиме загрузить какую-либо HTML-страницу, а затем "перейти" на неё?

Более точно, страница должна быть загружена в фоновом режиме целиком, вместе со всеми расположенными на ней скриптами, стилями, картинками и т.п. После того, как ***все*** элементы будут загружены, эта страница должна заменить текущее содержание документа, т.е. эффект должен быть таким, как будто пользователь щёлкнул по ссылке и страница загрузилась, но сделать это должен скрипт.

*Дополнение.* Загружаемая страница находится на том же домене. Содержимое адресной строки после загрузки неважно. Использовать какие-либо фреймворки запрещено - решение должно быть на "чистом" *JS*.

Comment: Из брутальных вариантов - зафетчить страницу с заинлайненными ресурсами и заменить корень dom.

Comment: может, в невидимый iframe загрузить страницу? А по окончании загрузки его развернуть во весь документ..

Comment: ещё вариант использовать [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM), но это пока экспериментальная технология.

Comment: @Sergiks Невидимый `iframe` не подходит, нужно заменить именно содержание документа. Shadow DOM - это интересно. Даже не знал о такой технологии.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Проблема, к сожалению, в том, что ресурсы не заинлайнить...

Answer (score 1):

На стороне клиента решить такую задачу можно, не совсем желательно.

**Сразу предупреждаю, лучшее решение выполняется *частично* на стороне сервера.**

Решение на клиенте это только iframe. По тому как любой другой вариант будет априори не правильным. Так как с клиента мы ограничены запросом страницы.

А вот более правильный вариант, отдавать с сервера уже шаблонизированную страницу строкой. А затем через js вставить ее содержимое в невидимый див и отрисовать его.

Оба варианта сложноваты, и если сложность второго очевидна, то в первом варианте вам придется разобраться с взаимодействием JS из основного окна в iframe. К тому же спецификация тега iframe устаревает, и скорее всего в ближайшем будущем он будет отменен.

## UPD.

В принципе коментатор прав по поводу обоих минусов, тогда, можно просто через тот же js заменить весь dom от корня. Но это очень жестокий вариант. После выполнения замены нужно **обязательно** вызвать событие *onload*

Comment: 1. возможен конфликт стилей и скриптов; 2. подгруженные скрипты не получат событие `document onload` и не выполнятся.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у нас есть документ index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='cp1251'>
    </head>

    <body> документ 1 </body>
    <script src='script1.js'></script>
</html>
```

И второй документ рядом new.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    </head>

    <body> документ 2 </body>
    <script src='script2.js'></script>
</html>
```

В первом скрипте выполняем запрос, получаем новый документ и по получению просто заменяем весь контент. Вот только скрипты и стили будут грузиться отдельно

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'new.php', true);
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        document.write(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

По получению ответа, можно записать временно его в элемент текущего документа. Затем искать картинки, скрипты, стили и рекурсивно загружать их

```
if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

    tmp = document.createElement('div');
    tmp.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(tmp);
    tmp.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

    resources = Array.from(tmp.querySelectorAll('script, img, link'));
    resources.forEach(function(e, i) {
        link = e.src || e.href;
        console.log(link);
    });

    // пройтись по массиву resources и всё загрузить
}
```

По окончанию загрузки ресурсов выполнить `document.write(xhr.responseText);`

Comment: стили, ссылающиеся на изображения; скрипты, подгружающие другие скрипты – всех не спарсить. Тот же requirejs.

Comment: @Sergiks, да, и картинки в стилях, тут уже никак... хотя можно же и получить путь и со стилей, но это огромный костыль